# "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party."

Tags: wcf

I am trying to implement the same functionalities of one WCF web service (which is working of course) to another WCF web service, but I encounter an exception: **{"An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."}**
and {**"The message could not be processed because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IBlueWebService/GetDataSourceList' is invalid or unrecognized."**}

I copied exactly same codes and same configuration and I use my client tool to call the new web service (I only changed the web service url to the new one), but it throws the exception.

Some forums told me to set the **establishSecurityContext** but it doesn't work also.

Please can somebody tell me what I am missing?

***Solution***

I tried to compare the wsdl files and I remarked that the new wcf web service had different action url from the old one, but I tried to use the same config file in client application (which is obviously looking for old wcf web service action url).
So in every operationcontract of new web service, I specified the action url and replyaction url for every operation and it works for me now.

Comment: What's the WSDL for the service look like?  It looks like the namespace or action aren't right..

Comment: The target namespace is same for both. But their name and the bindings are different

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".